# How to benefit from Hostelling International discount on Via Rail trains?

Tags: budget, canada, online-resources, bookings, via-rail

I would like to book a trip on Via Rail (the Canadian railway company) and I have seen that there is [a partnership between Hostelling International and Via Rail for a 10% discount](http://www.viarail.ca/en/fares-and-packages/special-fares/hostelling-international).

I have searched a way to book this trip with this discount online, but even with the [discount code provided on HI website](http://www.discounts.hihostels.ca/ResultLocalDiscountPartners.aspx?city=Montreal), I cannot really figure in the booking process how to benefit from it. Via Rail lists multiple `Discount Type`s (e.g. Promotional Coupon, Other Special Discounts, E-coupon, ...), and requires for each a `Discount Code` and sometimes a `Serial Number`.

I have tried with some of these types, and the discount code provided on HI website. But in the end I always get the same error:

> You have provided an invalid discount code and/or serial number for at least one passenger. Please correct (or remove) it below.

Is there a way to book it online? Otherwise, where can I take advantage of this fare? In HI hostels? at Via Rail stations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HI Hostels web site [says](http://www.hihostels.ca/viarail) that the Discount Type should be set to **Corporate Rate** and the Discount Code to **810945**. When I tried this, it did indeed take $11.60 off a $116 Escape fare booking.